# Custom partition on window 7 and ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, hard-drive

This question is related to many question but answer was not satisfying, hence posting new one.

I have 500GB HDD with 8GB ram along I5 processor in laptop[battery friendly install].I have following partition already.

**100 MB : Windows partition 

300 GB : Unpartitioned Space

65  GB : Windows Partition**

**I am ready to erase entire hard disk**, but want a prefect scheme.

What I want to achieve in my HDD is in order as below :

**Ubuntu

My shared NTFS drive for multimedia files

Windows [let it be in last , as I am ubuntu friendly]**

Now problem start when I try to do it in custom partition.Please tell me , i am totally open [ can erase window, reinstall all os.]
Also all i want a good battery friendly installation[second major]

My HDD partition dream as ascii

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|               |                                               |                     |
|     UBUNTU :) |              MULTIMEDIA+DATA                  |    WINDOWS :(       | 
|               |                                               |                     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I already thought

- / : 20 gb
- swap : 10gb
- /home : 60gb
- NTFS : rest
- windows:60gb

---

```
|               |                                               |                     |
|/+SWAP+HOME :) |              ntfs                             |    WINDOWS :(       | 
|               |                                               |                     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I have 320 Gig disk and 4 Gig RAM, I went with the following model

/ - 13G
/spare [for OS Image] - 38 * 1024 = 38912G
/home - 100 * 1024 = 102400G
/backup - 140 * 1024 = 143360G
swap - 4*1024*2 = 8192G

/spare and /backup will contain backup of OS and data respectively. If you have extra disks to take continuous backup, then you dont need these two drives. As I use only for office purpose, my 100 G hasn't reached 50% yet on /home.

As you want Windows also you can create rest Windows and keep your multimedia files in NTFS partition.

You can think about it as there is no hard rule to go. Please note that for me this is best way and I figured it out after erasing and reformatting for almost 8-10 times.

Also I assume you know that Windows has to be installed first and then Ubuntu and otherway round is not possible.

Comment: i appreciate your effort, but i am not asking about partition scheme, i am asking about procedure on how to do it.

Comment: Then thats a simple answer... First create 60 G partition and load windows on to that. Then I create your NTFS partition where you want to create multimedia files. Leave the rest space as non-partitioned space. Restart the computed with Live USB or CD. Once it boot with Live CD, click Try Ubuntu. Then click GParted and create the partitions as required by you. Then you can start installation assigning mount points to that. I hope this answers your question